# Is it okay to use floating point numbers as keys in objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it ok to use float numbers as keys in javascript objects? Woudn't be there potential problems with such objects?

Consider the below code:

```
var obj = {};
obj[1.2345]   = 10;
obj[10000]    = 10;
obj[10000.23] = 10;
```

Comment: Not except for the fact that you have to access the properties using the bracket notation

Comment: Probably best, if you're going to state your question two ways, to make them not opposites of each other. E.g., the answer to *"Is it ok to use float numbers as keys in javascript objects?"* is mostly "yes," but the answer to *"Woudn't be there potential problems with such objects?"* is mostly "no".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it ok to use float numbers as keys in javascript objects?

Yes, *mostly*. All property names (keys) are strings* (even the ones we think of as array indexes, in JavaScript's standard arrays, because [those aren't really arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)). So when you write

```
obj[1.2345] = 10;
```

what you're really writing is:

```
obj[String(1.2345)] = 10;
```

e.g.

```
obj["1.2345"] = 10;
```

and it's perfectly fine to have a property with the name `1.2345` (as a string) in an object.

The reason I said "mostly" above is that the floating-point numbers used by JavaScript (and most other languages) aren't perfectly precise; so if you did this:

```
obj[0.3] = 10;
```

and then

```
var key = 0.1;
key += 0.2;
console.log(obj[key]); // undefined
```

That's undefined because `0.1 + 0.2` comes out to `0.30000000000000004`, rather than `0.3`, and your object doesn't have a property named `0.30000000000000004`.

---

* *"...all property names...are strings..."* This was true up through ES5, but as of ES2015 (aka ES6), there's a new property name type: [`Symbol`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types-symbol-type). But most properties have string names, the use cases for `Symbol` are important but outnumbered by "normal" property names.